# WSGI: Use AJAX to get a string from a python script

Tags: python, ajax, cgi, wsgi

I am delving into WSGI & it is pretty difficult.

**What I am trying to do is something pretty simple: when I click a link I want to get the string "hello" from a python script & display "hello" in my HTML paragraph element.**

Now I have made WSGI python scripts that display HTML text, ie, serve a page using WSGI python, but not used Python, AJAX & WSGI together for the above mentioned purpose.

*Right now what happens is when I click the link in my HTML page, the paragraph element displays "error" not "hello". Where do you think I am going wrong; in python or javascript?*

Is my python script below correct?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from cgi import parse_qs, escape

def application(environ, start_response):

   return [ "hello" ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    srv = make_server('localhost', 8000, application)
    srv.serve_forever()
```

Maybe its my Javascript &/or HTML where I am wrong?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function onTest( dest, params )
        {
            var xmlhttp;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById( "bb" ).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("POST",dest,true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send( params ); 
        }


    -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="bb"> abcdef </p>
    <a href="javascript:onTest('aaa.py', '')">Click it</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Steps I take to test it:
- Run wsgi fake server script
- open browser & type http://localhost:8000/test.html
- click link in html page & get "error" back

My files wsgi.py, aaa.py & test.html are all in the same folder.

My Server:
    import threading
    import webbrowser
    import os
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

```
FILE = 'index.html'
PORT = 8000

def test_app(environ, start_response):

    if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':

        try:
            request_body_size = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
            request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            request_body = "0"

        try:
            response_body = str(int(request_body) ** 2)
        except:
            response_body = "error"

        status = '200 OK'
        headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
        start_response(status, headers)
        return [response_body]

    else:
        f = environ['PATH_INFO'].split( "?" )[0]
        f = f[1:len(f)]
        response_body = open(f).read()
        status = '200 OK'
        headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]
        start_response(status, headers)
        return [response_body]

def open_browser():
    """Start a browser after waiting for half a second."""

    def _open_browser():
        webbrowser.open('http://localhost:%s/%s' % (PORT, FILE))
        thread = threading.Timer(0.5, _open_browser)
        thread.start()

def start_server():
    """Start the server."""
    httpd = make_server("", PORT, test_app)
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    open_browser()
    print "Now serving on Port 8000"
    start_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `start_response`.  Use a call like:

```
start_response("200 OK", [('Content-type','text/plain')])
```

Comment: Thanks. That works if I am serving my own page, I run the script, then type http://localhost:8000 into my browser, but it doesn't work when I run my fake wsgi server, then run my html page in the browser & click the link. I still get "error". Maybe my server is the problem (see question for server)?

Comment: Where? Or has this answer become obsolete? I see `start_response()` in the above code snippets so I'm not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: @dwanderson He edited his question after being helped by my answer.  See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5150339/revisions .

Answer (score 0):

Error seems be from python script. Check whether aaa.py are ok with directly accessing with your IE or other browsers.

Comment: From @Matthew Flaschen answer, the python script works when I run it then type http...:8000 so I think the script is ok, but I am not sure I should be serving anything?

Comment: seems a little wired, and I suggest you to use firefox with firebug to monitor network after you click your anchor in test.html. Now you use 'POST' method to upload data, could you try to use 'GET' instead?

Answer (score 0):

> httpd.serve_forever()

has to be outside a function block

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "aaa.py" as the post url here. Then the server will look at the root for this file. e.g. localhost/aaa.py. You have to give the full path from the server root (without the server root path)

e.g. if the file located on /var/www/wsgi-scripts/aaaa.py
then the url should be /wsgi-scripts/aaaa.py.